# one function for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

i am currently drawing elements on the canvas:

```
  var head = new Kinetic.Ellipse({
    x: stage.width() / 2,
    y: 100,
    radius: {
            x: 50,
            y: 60
        },
    fill: '#DDDDDD',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 2
  });

  var neck = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
    x: stage.width() / 2,
    y: 180,
    sides: 4,
    radius: 70,
    fill: '#DDDDDD',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 2
  });

layer.add(neck);
layer.add(head);
```

and changing the color of these elements when clicked or touch, but i will have alot of elements on the screen and do not want the same amount of function to change each one.

is there a way to lets say combine the two below to be one function but effect the two above.

```
  head.on('touchstart, mousedown', function() {
    var current = this.getFill();
    var fill = "";
    switch (current) {
      case "#DDDDDD":
      fill = "#FFC926";
      break;
      case "#FFC926":
      fill = "#FF0000";
      break;
      case "#FF0000":
      fill = "#000000";
      break;
      default:
      fill= "#DDDDDD";
    }
    this.setFill(fill);
    layer.draw();
  });

  neck.on('touchstart, mousedown', function() {
    var current = this.getFill();
    var fill = "";
    switch (current) {
      case "#DDDDDD":
      fill = "#FFC926";
      break;
      case "#FFC926":
      fill = "#FF0000";
      break;
      case "#FF0000":
      fill = "#000000";
      break;
      default:
      fill= "#DDDDDD";
    }
    this.setFill(fill);
    layer.draw();
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract a common function, and use it like bellow

```
 var evaentListener =  function(obj) {
    return  function() {
        var current = obj.getFill();
        var fill = "";
        switch (current) {
          case "#DDDDDD":
          fill = "#FFC926";
          break;
          case "#FFC926":
          fill = "#FF0000";
          break;
          case "#FF0000":
          fill = "#000000";
          break;
          default:
          fill= "#DDDDDD";
        }
        obj.setFill(fill);
        layer.draw();
    }
}

head.on('touchstart, mousedown',evaentListener(this));

neck.on('touchstart, mousedown',evaentListener(this));
```